# Splitting a file every time the content of a given column changes

Tags: text-processing

I'm working with a text file and have run into an issue that I'm not able to solve despite some googling and asking around.

I would like to split this file (20,880 lines) into separate files based on the contents of column 2 (delimited with a `|`). I want a new file every time the content of column 2 changes. Unfortunately, the number of lines for each instance of column 2 is not regular, so I can't just split the file every `n` lines.

Here are the first few lines of the raw file:

```
>00000000|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7534_20160316|gene_callers_id:24
>00000001|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7537_20160321|gene_callers_id:78
>00000002|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7541_20160426|gene_callers_id:774
>00000003|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7544_20160502|gene_callers_id:1034
>00000004|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7547_20160512|gene_callers_id:330
>00000005|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7550_20160517|gene_callers_id:2094
>00000006|gene_cluster:GC_00001290|genome_name:r7534_20160316|gene_callers_id:76
>00000007|gene_cluster:GC_00001290|genome_name:r7537_20160321|gene_callers_id:358
>00000008|gene_cluster:GC_00001290|genome_name:r7541_20160426|gene_callers_id:1601
>00000009|gene_cluster:GC_00001290|genome_name:r7544_20160502|gene_callers_id:2134
```

I then sort it by the second column, giving me this:

```
>00006406|gene_cluster:GC_00000001|genome_name:r7534_20160316|gene_callers_id:1988
>00006409|gene_cluster:GC_00000001|genome_name:r7537_20160321|gene_callers_id:1059
>00006410|gene_cluster:GC_00000001|genome_name:r7537_20160321|gene_callers_id:1811
>00006407|gene_cluster:GC_00000001|genome_name:r7537_20160321|gene_callers_id:1947
>00006411|gene_cluster:GC_00000001|genome_name:r7537_20160321|gene_callers_id:643
>00006408|gene_cluster:GC_00000001|genome_name:r7537_20160321|gene_callers_id:759
>00006412|gene_cluster:GC_00000001|genome_name:r7541_20160426|gene_callers_id:1252
>00006415|gene_cluster:GC_00000001|genome_name:r7541_20160426|gene_callers_id:1920
>00006414|gene_cluster:GC_00000001|genome_name:r7541_20160426|gene_callers_id:2021
>00006413|gene_cluster:GC_00000001|genome_name:r7541_20160426|gene_callers_id:2094
```

But I haven't figured out how to split the file every time the second column changes. How can I go about splitting this file?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is 100% on topic and welcome here, but based on the example file you provided, you might also be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F"|" '{print > $2}' input_file
$ head gene_cluster*
==> gene_cluster:GC_00001105 <==
>00000000|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7534_20160316|gene_callers_id:24
>00000001|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7537_20160321|gene_callers_id:78
>00000002|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7541_20160426|gene_callers_id:774
>00000003|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7544_20160502|gene_callers_id:1034
>00000004|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7547_20160512|gene_callers_id:330
>00000005|gene_cluster:GC_00001105|genome_name:r7550_20160517|gene_callers_id:2094

==> gene_cluster:GC_00001290 <==
>00000006|gene_cluster:GC_00001290|genome_name:r7534_20160316|gene_callers_id:76
>00000007|gene_cluster:GC_00001290|genome_name:r7537_20160321|gene_callers_id:358
>00000008|gene_cluster:GC_00001290|genome_name:r7541_20160426|gene_callers_id:1601
>00000009|gene_cluster:GC_00001290|genome_name:r7544_20160502|gene_callers_id:2134
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for the fast reply :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'|' '$2 != out{close(out); out=$2} {print > out}'
```

If you don't close each output file as you go then once you get past a threshold of concurrently open files the awk script will either fail or slow down significantly depending on your awk version, e.g. see [error-awk-too-many-output-files-10-when-splitting-ssl-certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285560/error-awk-too-many-output-files-10-when-splitting-ssl-certificates) or [awk-cannot-open-04477c9a875b80-csv-for-output-too-many-open-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126553/awk-cannot-open-04477c9a875b80-csv-for-output-too-many-open-files)